# Gaussian Blur in JPanel. GraphicsUtilities missing ?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a gaussian blur filter on a `JPanel` and I found the following tutorial

> > http://www.curious-creature.org/2007/08/01/blurred-background-for-dialogs-extreme-gui-makeover-2007/

I have Swing installed and he mentions that all his resources come from within Swing:

> > "This method relies on GraphicsUtilities and GaussianBlurFilter from SwingX [...]"

However, in my case Eclipse does not seem to find any classes for neither `GraphicsUtilities` nor `GaussianBlurFilter`. Does anybody know a fix for that ?

Alternatively, does anybody know an alternative library/tutorial/way to achieve a gaussian blur on a `JPanel` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/) is not Swing but a different library, that's why you can't find it by default in the JDK.

Comment: Yup, just realized that :D. Just downloaded it, and it works... Thanks anyway!